# Sending emails with javamail using APN for host (Android)

Tags: android, email, jakarta-mail, apn

I want to send emails with [javamail-android](https://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/) but I'am using a host server different than usual ones (Gmail, Yahoo, Hotmail, etc). The host is accessed via APN throught the mobile data network, I don't know how configure this. Currently my code for sending email setup all fields like this:

```
    mailer.setFrom("myself@xxxxx.com");
    mailer.setUser("myself@xxxxx.com");
    mailer.setPassword("xxxxxxxxxx");
    mailer.setHost("smtp.xxxxx.xx");
    mailer.setPort(25);
    mailer.setSocketFactoryPort(25); // ?
```

I'm getting the next error **Unknown SMTP host: smtp.xxxxx.xx**. I know for sure that at least the above data is OK. But I don't know how to use the previous configuration on APN and "mobile-data". Is there something wrong with this configuration ? Do I have to change something to make it work with APN and mobile data network?

My code for sending email is almost the same described [here](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_(no_Intents)_in_Android).

Comment: BTW, you might want to switch to the official [JavaMail for Android](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#JavaMail_for_Android).  Accessing a different mail server should be just a matter of setting the properties that are appropriate for that server.  Of course, you need to know what those properties **are**, but the owner of the server should tell you that - host name, port number, SSL or not, etc.

Comment: But, there are any way to setup APN while sending email with javamail ? I'ts necesary to do it ? There is not access to the server via wifi .

Comment: Setting up APN and sending email are completely independent operations.  I don't know if or how a program can set up APN.  Normally it's set up when a mobile device is configured for the mobile network and doesn't need to change.  Once set up, it should provide TCP/IP access for all applications, including those using JavaMail.  The TCP/IP stack will choose whether to use wifi or mobile data depending on what's available.